# Vue.js - Wrong Checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

With Vue.js, I'm showing the list of items with a checkbox. Clicking on Checkbox will move the item down with strike-through. The issue is, when I click on the checkbox, the wrong checkbox is checked.

For eg, when I click on Apple checkbox, orange checkbox is checked.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d6encxe1/

Here's my code,

```js
var myApp = new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: {
    lists: [
      {title: 'Apple', isChecked: false},
      {title: 'Orange', isChecked: false},
      {title: 'Grapes', isChecked: false}
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filterLists: function(){
      return _.orderBy(this.lists, ['isChecked', false]);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    completeTask: function(e, i){
      e.preventDefault();
      this.lists[i].isChecked = !this.lists[i].isChecked;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.completed{
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="myApp">
  <ul>
      <li v-for="(list, index) in filterLists">
        <input type="checkbox" v-bind:id="'todo-' + index" v-on:change="completeTask($event, index)" />
        <span class="title" v-bind:class="{completed: list.isChecked}">{{list.title}}</span> 
        </li>
      
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: try moving `v-for` to `li` and put a `key` attribute on `li` that is unique (can be `title` in your case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key). A key uniquely identifies an element in Vue. If you do not use a key, Vue will try to re-use existing elements for performance.

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus
> reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key
> attribute for each item. An ideal value for key would be the unique id
> of each item.

You should *always* use a key when rendering list. Here I'm using the title of your list items, but ideally you should generate a unique key.

```
<li v-for="(list, index) in filterLists" :key="list.title">
```

Also you do not need to pass indexes around. Just pass the item itself.

```
v-on:change="completeTask(list)"
```

And in completeTask, check it off.

```
completeTask: function(task){
  task.isChecked = !task.isChecked
}
```

Finally, iterate over your `li` element and not your `ul` element.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6encxe1/8/).

Comment: I completely forget about the `key`. That fixed the issue.Thanks for pointing out `index` issue.. It's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The index screws things up, you can fix it by binding the checked state

```
<input type="checkbox" v-bind:checked="list.isChecked" v-bind:id="'todo-' + index" v-on:change="completeTask($event, index)" />
```

And changing the complete task to just pass the item in:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-bind:id="'todo-' + index" v-on:change="completeTask(list)" v-bind:checked="list.isChecked" />
```

See fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/d6encxe1/3/

You should remove the 'id' or use something other than the index of the loop because when you re-order the index doesn't change.

Comment: Another great solution without using `:key`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to put `v-for` in `<li>` instead of `<ul>`, or your will get several `<ul>` elements.

And you didn't provide a `key`. You should provide a unique key for the items. For example, if the `title` is unique, you can use it as the `key`, or you may need to add another attribute like `id`.

Besides, you can pass the entire list item to the method instead of just the index, because the indexes are changeable in your case:

```
v-on:change="completeTask($event, list)"
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/0r2yb0z6/1/